# TrueNAS Plex Jail DNS Error

Tags: dns, freenas, plex

Trying to install Plex on my server running TrueNAS-12.0-U1, but running into this error:

> Error: plexjail had a failure Exception: RuntimeError Message: DNS
> Exception: The DNS operation timed out after 30.00014615058899 seconds
> pkg.cdn.trueos.org could not be reached via DNS, check your network
> Partial plugin destroyed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and none of the answers was working. In the end I had to enable **DNS Relay** on my router.

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing, can you give any more information on what the problem was and how configuring DNS Relay might have solved it?

Comment: I was seeing the very same problem Greg asked about. "DNS Exception: The DNS operation timed out after 30.* seconds -some link- could not be reached via DNS"
Regardless of what I put in as the Jail's DNS config, or whether or not I used DHCP, the Jail's DNS query would fail. I could not look into the plugin jail as it gets destroyed once the install fails, but my guess is that the jail was querying the router's disabled DNS service even if told not to.

Comment: So you're saying the jail always tries to connect to the router's own DNS (ie dns == localhost), so if you don't have _some_ dns service on the router it can't look anything up.  A simple relay gets you out of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS providers in the network configuration of the Truenas computer, not the Jail/plugin configuration. To check if they work try to ping google.es for example in the shell

Comment: i run `ping google.es` and get the error `ping: cannot resolve google.es: Host name lookup failure`

Comment: Try settting your DNS providers manually in network -> global configuration. For example you can use 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 which are cloudflare DNS's.